# Stripe Display net income after Creating separate charges and transfers

Tags: stripe-payments

I was following this flow where I charge the user in my platform and pay the connected accounts  using stripe transfer.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#collecting-fees

[image]

On the stripe dashboard, the payment transaction appears like this:

[image]

The charge amount to the user ($66.40) and the amount transferred to connect account ($50.00).

One problem I have, is accounting wants to know where is the net income and they want to view it and wanted to make sure it was on the owner account.

I have explain to them that this is the part of the $66.40 charge, but they insist to show it with a dashboard of transaction.

Is there a way I could see this in stripe dashboard the net income receive by the account?
Consider the $100 charge example flow, where can I show them the $6.80 net income?

What they want is a detailed report of the payments to show proof the money was there.

- Transferred Amount to Connect1
- Transferred Amount to Connect2
- Application Net Income(Considered as Fee)
- Stripe Fees
- Other Fee (Not yet implemented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn’t be able to see this directly in the dashboard since you’ve created the Transfers separately. But using the API you could retrieve all of this info.
First, you’d have to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve) the PaymentIntent and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) on `charges.data.balance_transaction`. From that [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object) you would be able to get the amounts of the `net`(1)  and `fee` for each charge on this PaymentIntent. If there are multiple charges consider aggregating the response by summing the different Charges’ values. You could see the details of the fees on the `fee_details` [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-fee_details) to differentiate between `application_fee`(N/A in your current use case), `stripe_fee` or `tax`.

Next you need to [list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/list) all transfers related to the [transfer_group](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-transfer_group). From each item on that list you could get the `amount`(2) and the `destination` Account of that transfer. For this to work, you should associate the PaymentIntent/Charge with the different Transfers, by setting the same `transfer_group` value for both the Payment Intent and the subsequent Transfers.

You might also need to keep an eye on the refunds list since they might occur and would probably factor in your net amount as well, but that could be the topic for another day.

Once you have all of these you’d be able to calculate you’re real net amount which is the `(1) net - sum of (2) transfer amounts`.

So to summarize (in pseudo code):

- Transferred Amount to Connect1: from amount on the transfer list (filter by `destination = Connect1`)
- Transferred Amount to Connect2: from amount on the transfer list (filter by `destination = Connect2`)
- Stripe Fees: sum from the `charges.data.(each).balance_transaction.fee_details.amount` (filter by `type="stripe_fee"`)
- Other Fee (Not yet implemented): sum from the `charges.data.(each).balance_transaction.fee_details.amount` (filter by `type="tax"`)
- Application Net Income(Considered as Fee): `sum of charges.data.(each).balance_transaction.net - sum transfer amounts`